# Scilab scatter plot in a for loop

Tags: scatter-plot, scilab

I'm tryng to do a scatter plot in a for loop where I plot only the last points.
But when looking at my plotted points, they are the points obtained from my equation.

What can I do to only obtain and plot the last points?

Here is the code:

```
m=1000
z=4000
T=200
pr=101325
sigma=0.24
cc=sigma*10^(-18)
lambda=((1.38*10^(-23)*T)/(sqrt(2)*pr*cc))
p=%pi*2
for I=1:z
theta=(grand(m,1,"unf",0,p));
cx= cumsum(lambda*cos(theta));
cy= cumsum(lambda*sin(theta)); 
scatter((cx,cy))
xlabel(["x"]);
ylabel("y");
title("Partilcle Distribution");
end
```

Comment: Could you improve your question? What exactly do you mean by "last points"? I understand you have a for-loop which calculates ``cx`` and ``cy``. What you want is to pick only the last values (the 1000th value) in each loop of those matrices and plot them together?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to take the last values of `cx` and `cy` in each loop, one option is to create new arrays to store those values and plot them outside of the loop, like this:

```
...
x = zeros(1,z); //row matrix filled with zeros
y = zeros(1,z); //row matrix filled with zeros
for I=1:z
    theta = grand(m,1,"unf",0,p);
    cx = cumsum(lambda*cos(theta));
    cy = cumsum(lambda*sin(theta));

    //overwriting values
    x(I) = cx($); //the dollar sign ($) returns the last element 
    y(I) = cy($); //of a row or a column in a matrix
end
scatter(x,y);
xlabel("x");
ylabel("y");
title("Partilcle Distribution");
```